# How to know which DMVs relate to each other?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

Is there any way to know which DMVs/DMFs are related to each other?

Some of them are well known or obvious, like sys.dm_exec_connections JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ON session_id = session_id, or the DMVs for missing indexes.

However, for example, I would like to know what other DMVs sys.dm_exec_sessions joins with on session_id.   Session_id does not exist in sys.columns.  Also, the queries here do not list anything for DMVs.

A long, long time ago Microsoft published a large .pdf poster with all of the system views for SQL Server 2005, so I'm looking for something like the for DMVs/DMFs in SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You could cheat and use [Glen Berry's](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/category/dmv-queries/). The docs list the [relationship cardinalities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#relationship-cardinalities) at the bottom for `sys.dm_exec_requests`, `sys.dm_exec_connections`, `sys.dm_exec_cursors`, `sys.dm_db_session_space_usage`.

Here's the [map for 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=39083) that you're looking for. You'd just need to account for new DMVs [Here is a mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of system tables to system views. - [scsimon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/95107/scsimon)